# Logging and multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, logging, pthreads, openmp

I noticed that most loggers are advertised as thread safe.

What does it mean?

Are they safe against a specific threading library or can they be safe in any multithreading environment (e.g. PThread, Boost threads, C++11 threads, Win32 threads, OpenMP threads, ...)?

Comment: the concept of a mutex is not library specific. usually loggers do use mutex's to stop threads to interfere each other. a thread safe logger is meant to run on every kind of thread.

Comment: @user1810087: from what I could [read](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.programming.threads/Z-e5udakt98), the concept of mutex is library specific. However, since e.g. both OpenMP and Boost threads' are based on PThreads (in UNIX), they use the same PThreads' mutex. Maybe that is why they are compatible.

Comment: they are not specific, it's just a bad idea (and also really ugly) to mix them. you even could write your own mutex and use it on every type of thread, as long as the mutex instance is not thread local.

Comment: I do not intend to mix them. I just want to be sure that a logging library works with any multi-threading library.

Answer (score 2):

It means you won't get something like this in your log files:

```
this is the line from the firsThis is line from the second thread
t thread
```

Usually it means that loggers use required locking when they write to the stream in any supported environment.

Answer (score 2):

If a logger is thread safe that means you can call its functions from any threads (be it pthread or boost or openmp). That is usually done by using mutexes to prevent simultaneous output. Without them your program may output mixed lines or even crash if log is used from different threads.